# Hashtags in Arabic language crashes the app

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring, hashtag

I have a hashtags resolver UITextView extension that turns any word with "#" before it to a tappable blue link. It is working fine except when tapping on Arabic hashtags.

```
extension UITextView {

func resolveHashAndMentionTags(){

    // turn string in to NSString
    let nsText:NSString = self.text as NSString

    // this needs to be an array of NSString.  String does not work.
    let words:[NSString] = nsText.components(separatedBy: " ") as [NSString]

    // you can't set the font size in the storyboard anymore, since it gets overridden here.
    let attrs = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 14.0)!//UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13.0)

    ]

    // you can staple URLs onto attributed strings
    let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: nsText as String, attributes:attrs)

    // tag each word if it has a hashtag or mention
    for word in words {

        // found a word that is prepended by a hashtag!
        if word.hasPrefix("#") {

            // a range is the character position, followed by how many characters are in the word.
            // we need this because we staple the "href" to this range.
            let matchRange:NSRange = nsText.range(of: word as String)

            // convert the word from NSString to String
            // this allows us to call "dropFirst" to remove the hashtag
            var stringifiedWord:String = word as String

            // drop the hashtag
            stringifiedWord = String(stringifiedWord.dropFirst())

                print(stringifiedWord)
                attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.link, value: "hash://\(stringifiedWord)", range: matchRange)
         //   }

        } else if word.hasPrefix("@") {

            // a range is the character position, followed by how many characters are in the word.
            // we need this because we staple the "href" to this range.
            let matchRange:NSRange = nsText.range(of: word as String)

            // convert the word from NSString to String
            // this allows us to call "dropFirst" to remove the mention@
            var stringifiedWord:String = word as String

            // drop the hashtag
            stringifiedWord = String(stringifiedWord.dropFirst())


            attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.link, value: "mention://\(stringifiedWord)", range: matchRange)
           // }
        }
    }

    // we're used to textView.text
    // but here we use textView.attributedText
    // again, this will also wipe out any fonts and colors from the storyboard,
    // so remember to re-add them in the attrs dictionary above
    self.attributedText = attrString
}
```

Then in my posts cell i call the `UITextViewDelegate` function.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {

    let path = URL.absoluteString
    switch URL.scheme! {
    case "hash" :
        let hash = path.removingPercentEncoding?.components(separatedBy: "://").last
        print(hash!) // ---> Retriving tapped on hash name correctly
        delegate?.hashTableViewCell(self, shouldSelectTag: hash!)
    case "mention" :
        let mention = path.removingPercentEncoding?.components(separatedBy: "://").last
        print(mention!) // ---> Retriving tapped on mention name correctly
        delegate?.mentionTableViewCell(self, shouldSelectTag: mention!, userId: nil)
    default:
        print("Just a regular link \(path.removingPercentEncoding!)")
    }
    return true
}
```

As i mentioned above the code it is working fine for english letters but when tapping on an arabic hashtag or mention it crashes in the `AppDelegate`.

> Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1030fcb94)

I tried to debug with break points to know where the error is exactly but actually i found out that it is crashing even before entering the `UITextViewDelegate` function. So now i have no clue at all where the error could be exactly.

Maybe there could be some kind of an issue with arabic letters being used as a link in a `UITextView`?

Here is the stack trace.

> - thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1030fcb94)
>     frame #0: 0x00000001030fcb94 libswiftFoundation.dylib`function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed, Arg[1] = Dead> of static Foundation.URL._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC(Swift.Optional<__ObjC.NSURL>) -> Foundation.URL + 288
>     frame #1: 0x0000000103045f24 libswiftFoundation.dylib`static Foundation.URL._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC(Swift.Optional<__ObjC.NSURL>) -> Foundation.URL + 20
>     frame #2: 0x0000000101199c68 OOL`@objc PostTableViewCell.textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:) at PostTableViewCell.swift:0
>     frame #3: 0x000000018e1e397c UIKit`-[_UITextViewInteractableLink allowInteraction:] + 360
>     frame #4: 0x000000018e1e2698 UIKit`-[_UITextViewInteractableItem handleTap] + 40
>     frame #5: 0x000000018db64548 UIKit`-[UITextGestureClusterLinkInteract smallDelayRecognizer:] + 296
>     frame #6: 0x000000018db7ccd0 UIKit`-[UIGestureRecognizerTarget _sendActionWithGestureRecognizer:] + 64
>     frame #7: 0x000000018db812c4 UIKit`_UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions + 124
>     frame #8: 0x000000018d659aa8 UIKit`_UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 320
>     frame #9: 0x000000018d510c38 UIKit`-[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 732
>     frame #10: 0x000000018db6ab34 UIKit`_UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 1084
>     frame #11: 0x000000018db6a6a4 UIKit`-[UIGestureEnvironment _deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:] + 404
>     frame #12: 0x000000018db69800 UIKit`-[UIGestureEnvironment _updateGesturesForEvent:window:] + 276
>     frame #13: 0x000000018d50ef44 UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 3180
>     frame #14: 0x000000018d4dff64 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 340
>     frame #15: 0x000000018de3531c UIKit`__dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2364
>     frame #16: 0x000000018de378a8 UIKit`__handleEventQueueInternal + 4760
>     frame #17: 0x000000018de307c0 UIKit`__handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 152
>     frame #18: 0x0000000183fa697c CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
>     frame #19: 0x0000000183fa68fc CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88
>     frame #20: 0x0000000183fa6184 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 204
>     frame #21: 0x0000000183fa3d5c CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1048
>     frame #22: 0x0000000183ec3e58 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
>     frame #23: 0x0000000185d70f84 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 100
>     frame #24: 0x000000018d54367c UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 236
>
>   - frame #25: 0x0000000101063348 OOL`main at AppDelegate.swift:22
>       frame #26: 0x00000001839e056c libdyld.dylib`start + 4

Comment: When it crashes, type "bt" at the (lldb) prompt.  Paste the resulting stack trace into your question.

Comment: @PhillipMills here you are

Comment: Do you have a sample text with value causing the crash?

Comment: Any arabic letters text is crashing for instance the last one i tried was قرده# maybe the hash has to be on the other side like the english? for instance #hello...?? Like this #قرده  but makes no sense to me. Because when i print out the stringified word on the console it is correct. And also tinted in blue as the other english hashtags.

Comment: Thanks for the sample value, I tested and I think that's because `let urlTest = URL.init(string: "hash://\(stringifiedWord)")` is `nil` with the arabic text as url, and since the delegate method is with `URL` param and not `String` param, it causes the crashes internally (inner Apple code doesn't do a check on the url validity and crash). That's my guess.

Comment: @Larme this is very possible and if that is true this means the logic im using to resolve the hashtags with and connecting them with links won't ever work with arabic letter...!!!

Comment: I don't know what you want to do afterwards with the delegate, but you can `.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)` on the `stringifiedWord` before, and since you already remove the percent escape encoding in the delegate, that should be okay for that.

Comment: @Larme as i mentioned in the question that the delegate function is not called at all. And the crash is before even calling the delegate function. I added break points and the function is not called at all. When letter are in english it is called.

Comment: When adding percent escaping, the url is then not nil, and on tap the delegate method is then called.

Comment: @Larme MAAAAN it worked.... i added percentage encoding to the stringified word as you mentioned in my UITextView extension. Just write the answer down there and i will accept and upvote you deserve it man.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I guess could be the issue (either on tag or hash)...

You do:

```
attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.link, value: "hash://\(stringifiedWord)", range: matchRange)
```

But if you'd use a `URL` object (`let url = URL.init(string:"hash://\(stringifiedWord)")`) you'll see it may be `nil` in case of invalid string url and in your case arabic characters seem to be invalid.

The delegate method `func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool` is giving a `URL` object in parameters, and because your method is not called when you don't have a valid url, I guess that inner line in Apple's code assume it's a valid url, doesn't check it and crashes. That would explain why your method isn't called and crash before entering yours.

Solution: Use percent escaped characters.
Instead of putting `value: "hash://\(stringifiedWord)"`, do `value: "hash://\(stringifiedWord.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed))"` or other character set allowed.

In the delegate method you are already removing the percent escape: `let hash = path.removingPercentEncoding?.components(separatedBy: "://").last` so you don't have to add anything there.

Additional note:
You are doing `if word.hasPrefix("#")` and `if word.hasPrefix("@") almost the same thing (just the scheme change), you could simplify/factorize that, sample code not tested:

```
let dict = ["#":"mention://", "@": "hash://"]
for (key, value) in dict
{
   if word.hasPrefix(key)
   {
       let matchRange:NSRange = nsText.range(of: word as String)
       var stringifiedWord:String = word as String
       stringifiedWord = String(stringifiedWord.dropFirst(key.count))
       let espcapedWord  = stringifiedWord.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed
       let stringURL = "\(value)\(escapedWord)"
       if let url = URL.init(string:stringURL) //That should you avoid any crash just in case
       {
           attrString.addAttribute(.link, value: stringURL, range: matchRange)
       }
       else
       {
            print("Oooops with \(stringifiedWord) invalid URL: \(stringURL)")
       }
   }
}
```

Edit: Depending on the iOS version (tested on Simulator), it could make it crash, or simply not call the delegate method because of the invalid URL.

Comment: I will test your code simplification and if there is any edit needed to the code i will do it. Thanks again :))))

Comment: I wish I had +20. You've just helped me solve a production crash