# Convert attribute to URL / NSURL

Tags: ios, swift, url, nsattributedstring

I am working on a `UITextView` that is populated by a `NSAttributedString`.

I use the following code to extract the URL out of the attributed string:

```
if let attribute = self.textStorage.attribute(NSAttributedString.Key.link, at: characterIndex, effectiveRange: nil){
    let url = URL(string: (attribute as AnyObject).debugDescription ?? "");
    print("URL: \(url.absoluteString)");
}
```

It does not seem like an efficient way to get the `URL`, because I am converting the attribute to its debug description, then using that to initialize a new `URL`.

Is there a more "official" way to get the `URL` from the attribute?

Comment: What is `attribute` class? Isn't it already a `String`? So why, no doing, if let attribute = self.textStorage... as? String`, or  `as? URL` if it's already an `URL` object.

Comment: The attribute is of type Any, when I attempt to cast it I get a cast error even thought setting a breakpoint just above the print statement reveals the attribute is of type “NSURL.” Is there a more effective way to get the object from the key value store?

Comment: Then `if let attribute = self.textStorage... as? URL{ print("URL: \(attribute.absoluteString)"); }` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never had a issue when casting `.link` value to either `String` or `URL`, like so:

```
if let urlString = (attribute as? String) ?? (attribute as? URL)?.absoluteString {
    print("URL: \(urlString)")

    // URL from string
    let url = URL(string: urlString)
}
```

I faced some issues in the past when casting `.link` value alone to `String`, here in my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47676891/1244597) @RasheshBosamiya in comments also faced this issue, and seems the value of `NSAttributedString.Key.link` can either be `URL` or `String` depending on what/how it is set.

Comment: I'll recommend to save URL, it should help you detect quicker if you can have an issue with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48156375/1801544