# UITextView delegate method not calling in UITableViewCell using swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, delegates, uitextview

I am trying to make a specific text as link and everything working fine except my link text not calling delegate methods and on long press application got crashed without any error.

I did everything clearly even i did the same functionality in other controller and it works perfectly but not working in my other controller.

I need guidance like may be i don't have enough information about it.

```
class MobileLoadBundleCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {

//MARK: - IBOutlet

@IBOutlet weak var txtDescription: UITextView!

//MARK: - Variable

let urlApp = URL(string: "link")

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    
    if self.reuseIdentifier == "BalanceCell" {
        self.txtDescription.delegate = self
    }
}

func configCell() {
    
    let str = "Check your remaining usage details from my app"
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str)
    let foundRange = attributedString.mutableString.range(of: "my app")
    attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: "my app", range: foundRange)
    
    let linkAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
        .foregroundColor: UIColor(named: "ColorSetPink")!,
        .underlineColor: UIColor(named: "ColorSetPink")!,
        .underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue
    ]
    
    self.txtDescription.linkTextAttributes = linkAttributes
    self.txtDescription.attributedText = attributedString
}

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
    
    if (URL.absoluteString == "my app") {
        if let url = urlApp {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

}

Comment: I highly recommend to connect the delegate of the text field in Interface Builder.

Comment: I already did that. as i mentioned i did everything right and in other controller its working fine for me

Comment: `Links in text views are interactive only if the text view is selectable but noneditable. That is, if the value of the UITextViewisSelectable property is true and the isEditable property is false.` from the doc of the method, is it the case?

Comment: @MubashirMushir I'm not sure if you're aware but you're using very aggressive language and it may lead to people being less willing to help you.

Comment: @GuyKogus i am really sorry to if you feel that i dont even think about it but i realize that. thank you for your guidance.

Comment: @Larme i tried it and compare with my working controller. i spend many hours on it but still not getting my mistake. Please guide if there are other things to do. thank you

Comment: i got this error too **connection to daemon was invalidated**

Comment: "and on long press application got crashed without any error." wait, I didn't see that, you got a crash? I thought it was a dummy value for the StackOverflow question, but `attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: "my app", range: foundRange)`; could you put instead of `my app`, a REAL URL? like `http://www.stackoverflow.com`? Just to be sure? Why? Because it's expecting a valid URL String (because internally, it's using `URL(string: theValue)` and will crash if it's not valid.

Comment: Related to previous comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48154641/hashtags-in-arabic-language-crashes-the-app/48156375#48156375 and you don't have a stacktrace in console like the one in the question (or another stack trace) when it crashes?

Comment: @KishanBhatiya this condition was applied for other purpose. and its working fine and i just reattached delegate many time

Comment: Yes application got crashed on long press @Larme

Comment: If you use a real link, it worked? Because clearly `URL.absoluteString == "my app"` shouldn't never be true, since you can't have a space in an URL.

Comment: I am using this value only for comparison. once i hit this link and get it in delegate method of uitextview and mainly problem is that delegate method not  calling

Comment: "mainly problem is that delegate method not calling" No, mainly problem is that's it's crashing. Did you try as I suggested to put there `attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: "my app", range: foundRange)` no `"my app"`, but `"http://www.stackoverflow.com"` and see if the delegate is called? Because in the linked question that was exactly the problem, and the delegate method wasn't called, because it crashed internally just before calling it...

Comment: I just tried with "my app", and it's not called (while on a real URL, it's working). I guess that now they check if it's a valid URL (and don't make it crash). But depending ont the value you put, if you do `URL(string: theValue)` and if it's nil, then the delegate method won't be called. I got a crash on iOS 12.4 simulator, but not on iOS 13.... Is that your case?

Comment: Firstly larme thank you so much for your concern it mean alot to me and you were right application was crashed due to string value and my delegate method working fine now.

Comment: No its something else..  but answer was same as mine and i just got result from your guidance.