# Swift Crashlytics EXC_BREAKPOINT error meaning

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

I am seeing this report in **Firebase Crashlytics**:

[image]

But I can not figure out what this means? I have 5 different open bugs actually but they all look like the example! There is always the *17 Wishlists DropDownForWebView*  and it is always *EXC_BREAKPOINT* .

Another example:

[image]

Can anyone explain me what this means? Any idea how I can fix it? Quite annoying...

The app is live at the moment:

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/wishlists-dein-wunschzettel/id1503912334

I am happy for every help!

**Update**:

My `DropDownView`:

```
//MARK: DropDownView
class DropDownViewForWebView: UIView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {

var dropOptions = [DropDownOption]()

var tableView = UITableView() // LINE 18

var delegate : DropDownProtocol!

var selectedWishlistDelegate: SelectedWishlistProtocol?

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
```

I have a `textView` that handles `URLs`. This my helper function to add a `hyperlink`:

```
func hyperLink(originalText: String, hyperLink: String, urlString: String) {

    let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    style.alignment = .left

    let attributedOriginalText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: originalText)
    let linkRange = attributedOriginalText.mutableString.range(of: hyperLink)
    let fullRange = NSMakeRange(0, attributedOriginalText.length)
    attributedOriginalText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.link, value: urlString, range: linkRange)
    attributedOriginalText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: style, range: fullRange)
    attributedOriginalText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.darkCustom, range: fullRange)
    attributedOriginalText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineColor, value: UIColor.darkCustom, range: fullRange)
    attributedOriginalText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Medium", size: 15)!, range: fullRange)

    self.linkTextAttributes = [
        kCTForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.darkCustom,
        kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
        ] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]

    self.attributedText = attributedOriginalText
}
```

How I call it:

```
cell.linkTextView.hyperLink(originalText: "Open link".localized(), hyperLink: "Open link".localized(), urlString: currentWish.link)
```

`currentWish.link` can be anything. Doesn't have to be a valid `URL`. I validate it when tapping the link.

Comment: have you checked line 18 in your code file referenced in the crash report?

Comment: @Volk updated my question, not quite sure if that helps :/

Comment: Maybe... You have a `UITextView` that handle links? You might have an invalid URL. Are you using that? Are you using `NSAttributedString` and `.link`?

Comment: @Larme I am using a `textView` but I am only passing the `URL` inside a `callback`

Comment: That URL might be the culprit. How is created the url?

Comment: @Larme it can be any text. I check it in the `closure`. But I validate it before opening it

Comment: Can be any text. How is it created? It crashes before, so it might not be a valid URL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227276/discussion-between-chris-and-larme).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crash is happening inside iOS hidden code, just before calling the `UITextViewDelegate` method [`textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:interaction:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1649337-textview).

It's the same issue as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48154641/hashtags-in-arabic-language-crashes-the-app/48156375#48156375). To reproduce your bug, you can put for your links Korean text (`한국어 텍스트`, ie "korean text" according to Google Translate), Arabic text (`نص عربي`, ie "arabic text" according to Google Translate), etc. You can search on the Internet for sample "strange" text (ie, not "a-z characters).

What's happening:

- Setting:

  ```
  attributedText.addAttribute(.link, value: INVALIDSTRINGVALUE, range: linkRange)
  aTextView.attributedText = someAttributedText
  ```
- User Taping on link
- Apple internal code that will call later textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:interaction:)
- `textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:interaction:)`
- `linkTappedCallbackClosure(url: URL)`
- `openURL(_ urlString: String)` where you do:

  ```
  guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
      showInvalidUrlAlert()
      return
  }
  ```

So you check if the URL is valid, but too late. The code crash inside iOS code.

So before setting the url with `hyperLink(originalText:hyperLink:urlString:)` check there if it's a valid URL (ie `URL(string: urlString) != nil`), and if not, call `showInvaludURLAlert()`.

Ok, but that will fix only the new entries, not the current values that will make it crash.

To fix the older entries, you can decide to remove in your database all the invalid URL. But it will remove maybe infos that user thought to be tags, or something else extra field.

An extra code, possibility maybe:
Iterate over your database.
Add a boolean field "hasBeenFixed" to your database.
For each invalid URL (meaning `URL(string: thatValue) == nil)`), percent escape it., change the value hasBeenFixed to true
It should avoid the crash (to verify) if the user tries to tap on the link.
When showing the value to the user, (when editing), if `hasBeenFixed == true`, show the value with percent escape removed. Then, when the user will try to validate it will have the pop-up alert, and will need to fix it. When saving a valid URL then, change the `hasBeenFixed` to `false`.

Comment: hey Larme! Thanks again for your help, definitely deserved that bounty. 

I just realized that there is another problem quite related to this, could you maybe have look at it ? :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65719912/swift-getting-url-from-share-extension-or-webview-returning-invalid-value