# iOS app crashes when tapping URL within UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I'm trying to setup a UITextView with multiple links within the text. My implementation is based on the suggestion described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52262391/8200515). Most links work as expected, however tapping on some of them makes the app crash with the following error `EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x185646694)`:
[Crash error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoRt9.png)
[Call stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxYwb.png)

My UITextView configuration code:

```
private var actionableLinks = [(String, ()->Void)]() // each link = (actionableString, tapAction)

private func setupMessageText() {
    guard messageTextView != nil else { return }
        
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacingBefore = 16
        
    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: messageText, attributes: [
        .font: messageTextView.font!,
        .foregroundColor: messageTextView.textColor!,
        .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle
    ])
        
    addActionableLinks(to: attributedText)
        
    messageTextView?.attributedText = attributedText
}
    
private func addActionableLinks(to attributedText: NSMutableAttributedString) {
    actionableLinks.forEach {
        let actionableString = $0.0
            
        if let nsRange = messageText.nsRange(of: actionableString) {
            attributedText.addAttribute(.link, value: actionableString, range: nsRange)
        }
    }
}
```

To handle the tap action, I've imlpemented the proper UITextViewDelegate method:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
    let tappedLinkString = URL.absoluteString

    if let link = actionableLinks.first(where: { $0.0 == tappedLinkString }) {
        let tapAction = link.1
        tapAction()

        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

My storyboard configuration for this screen (I have setup the UITextView delegate in the storyboard):
[Storyboard Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUI0u.png)

Any insights would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I suspect the link to be invalid. `if let nsRange = messageText.nsRange(of: actionableString), URL(string: actionableString) != nil {` might be the fix. If you can reproduce, could you provide the `actionableString` which is causing the issue?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65656646/swift-crashlytics-exc-breakpoint-error-meaning  & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48154641/hashtags-in-arabic-language-crashes-the-app/48156375#48156375 since that might be the issue (there are explanations)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, and nice insight. The string I use as a link is in fact just a normal string and not a URL. I based my implementation on [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52262391/8200515) and nothing was mentioned there. 
The string for the link that is causing the crash is "new terms and conditions", and the one that succeeds is "support".

Comment: And as said (in the explaination see both links), if the "link" is `"new terms and conditions"`, converted to `URL`, with `URL(string: thatString)` internally by Apple, just before calling `textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:)`, it's nil and make it crash., because space are invalid. Percent escape them (see second linked question), and maybe add a scheme to them: `yourApp://` as prefix.

Comment: Nice catch indeed! I had that suspicion after reading the questions you linked. I'll test it right away

Comment: What is the actual actionableString guy?

Answer (score 3):

Issue solved! Thanks to [Larme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1801544/larme) for the quick insights and resources.

It was indeed a case of trying to use a bad string as a link within the UITextView that internally was being converted to a URL. Since this was a string with spaces in it, internal conversion to URL by Apple was failing.

My string "support" was linking properly and it worked, but a different string "new terms and conditions" was failing.

## The solution

To solve the issue, I used percent encoding when adding the link attribute to the UITextView's attributed text.

```
private func addActionableLinks(to attributedText: NSMutableAttributedString) {
    actionableLinks.forEach {
        let actionableString = $0.0
            
        if let nsRange = messageText.nsRange(of: actionableString) {
            let escapedActionableString = escapedString(actionableString)
            attributedText.addAttribute(.link, value: escapedActionableString, range: nsRange)
        }
    }
}
    
private func escapedString(_ string: String) -> String {
    return string.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed) ?? string
}
```

I also changed the delegate method to check for a match to an escaped string:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
    let tappedLinkString = URL.absoluteString
        
    for (actionableString, tapAction) in actionableLinks {
        let escapedActionableString = escapedString(actionableString)
            
        if escapedActionableString == tappedLinkString {
            tapAction()
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could have kept your shouldInteractLogic with just: `let tappedLinkString = URL.aboluteString.removingPercentEncoding` and your `first(where:)`.

Comment: Oh, cool! I'll use that, it's way cleaner. Thanks a lot!